# pyspark.pandas is not able to encode strings

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am trying to encode strings using pyspark.pandas API, available on pyspark 3.2.0.

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
a = {'a':1,'b':2}
df = ps.DataFrame([a])
series_columns = df.columns
b = ps.Series(series_columns).str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

Doing it I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/strings.py", line 1035, in encode
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

Has anyone else faced this problem? Is there any roadmap to implement this item? Or is there any way to do this without using to_pandas() function?

Comment: using UDF only for encoding seems overkill, have you tried built-in [`encode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.encode) function?

Comment: The built-in encode function works fine, but I'm migrating some pandas code to the pyspark pandas API, and I would like to keep the code with as few changes A possible.

Comment: I totally understand that, as I'm in the same situation. But migrating pandas to pyspark has to be taken care seriously and requires lots of work if you really want to get all of the performance value from Spark engine

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.